# Add to file if exists and create if not

Tags: bash, echo

I am working on a bash script that needs to take a single line and add it to the end of a file if it exists, and if it does not exist create the file with the line.

I have so far:

```sh
    if [ ! -e /path/to/file ]; then
        echo $some_line > /path/to/file
    else
        ???
    fi
```

How do I perform the operation that should go in the else (adding the line of text to the existing file)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use two angles: `echo $some_line >> /path/to/file`

Answer (score 23):

**>** creates the file if it doesn't exist; if it exists, overwrites it.

**>>** creates the file if it doesn't exist; if it exists, appends to it.

```
if [ ! -e /path/to/file ]; then
   echo $some_line > /path/to/file
else
   echo $some_line >> /path/to/file
fi
```

Comment: use just echo $some_line >> /path/to/file will be sufficient since >> creates the file if it doesn't exist

Comment: Yes you are right. I just gave the sample to Mark Roddy as he did.